# How to Transfer Elements that Match a Predicate from One Vector to Another in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl, std

Given two vectors of copyable elements and a predicate over those items, what is an efficient and idiomatic method for:

1. Removing matching items from the first vector
2. Appending matching items to the second vector

The following snippet reflects my current thinking, but it does require two passes over the source vector.

```
vector<int> source{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
vector<int> target;

auto predicate = [](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; };

std::for_each(source.begin(), source.end(), [&predicate, &target](int n) {
    if (predicate(n)) {
        target.push_back(n);
    }
});

auto it = std::remove_if(source.begin(), source.end(), predicate);
source.erase(it, source.end());
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd use [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) to partition `source`into two parts.

```
auto itr = std::partition(source.begin(), source.end(), predicate);

target.insert(target.end(), itr, source.end());

source.resize(itr - source.begin());
```

If the ordering needs to remain the same then use [`stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

Comment: I think that while `target` starts as empty in the original question's example, the code should work by appending to `target` even if it already has some contents.

Comment: then instead of constructing `target`, you can insert into it target. `target.insert(target.end(), itr, source.end())`

Comment: not relevant for `int`, but if this were an unknown type I'd use `std::move_iterator`s for the insertion

Comment: @OP: Notice that if you only work with iterators, you might no longer need extra vector and just use the partitioned vector.

Comment: To be clear, the context here is that both source and destination vectors are long-lived and both pre-date and post-date this particular operation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @acraig5075, that `stable_partition`, followed by copy and erase will do what you want.

However, if you don't want to shuffle elements around in the source container (probably a futile wish, IMHO), you can do it in a loop: (untested code)

```
auto itr = source.begin();
while (itr != source.end()) {
   if (predicate(*itr)) {
      target.push_back(*itr);
      itr = source.erase(itr);
   } else
      ++itr;
}
```

Note that this will "slide down" the elements of elements one at a time as they are moved into `target`, which is why I opined that avoiding this was probably foolish. (Note: If you're working with `list`, then it is less foolish)